# How to remove error Eclipse project indicator if I don't have any error?

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-kepler

I'm having an indication that my project has errors but I don't get any error in any file.
That indication is as well on Java Resources folder inside the project.

[image]

**Error log**

```
Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
An exception stack trace is not available.
```

**Problems**

```
An error occurred while filtering resources
line 1 - Maven configuration problem
```

How to remove this error in Eclipse project folder?
Any ideas!

Comment: what kind of errors do you get?

Comment: How could I know? Is there any place to look it?

Comment: Window (top bar) -> show view -> error log _or_ ALT+SHIFT+Q and L

Comment: Look in the `Problems` view. You can also delete error markers in this view

Comment: Maven -> Update Project... resolved this problem. Thank you both for helping me to find the problem!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maven > Update project

This resolved my problem as I pointed out in a comment from 2014

Comment: why such issues occur at first place in eclipse? Is there any better solution to ensure such thing will never occur at all?

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to most answers did `Maven > Update Project...` not solve this problem.

I ended up with removing and re-importing the project.

Answer (score 2):

Please try 
Maven -> Update Project
resolved this problem for me

Answer (score 2):

I just experienced the same issue. My project's pom serves as a child. maven update was the first thing I tried. I ended up deleting project from workspace, clearing .settings, .classpath, .project, reimporting and once again eclipse agreed to let maven play too :)